# Debugging vague iOS runtime errors?

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm trying to get a React-Native iOS app working, and after fighting through several compiler errors and spending a few hours in dependency hell, I got the app to compile successfully. Now when I run it, I see the splash screen and it immediately crashes with this error:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I figured I'd narrow down the location of the crash, so I added a breakpoint to `main.m`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  @autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
  }
}
```

But when I try stepping into `UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]))`, the app crashes. How can I debug this crash if the error message tells me nothing and the debugger doesn't let me inspect anything?

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set an exception breakpoint:

- Go to Breakpoints navigator (Cmd+8).
- Click + in lower left corner.
- Select "Exception breakpoint..."

Run your project again. It should break on the line of code where the exception occurs.